# Way to get INFO status for a redis cluster as a whole?

Tags: redis, monitoring, health-monitoring

I've got a 6-node (3 primary, 3 secondary) cluster. I can get stats from individual nodes (e.g. instantaneous_ops_per_second) using INFO, and I can get some information on the cluster config using CLUSTER INFO.

Is there a way to get the stats from INFO, but for the whole cluster? Using the -c switch to connect in cluster mode doesn't seem to change the output, and googling isn't revealing anything that seems to be useful (though I'm getting plenty of tips on things to monitor in general at least...)

I'd *prefer* not to have to use an external program to combine the stats, though that's an obvious solution - I'm hoping for something that's built in to redis that'll let me look at, for example, the number of commands per second the whole cluster is processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
redis-cli --cluster call <ip>:<port> INFO
```

Where `<ip>` and `<port>` are one of the cluster's nodes.

Comment: ... interesting. Technically not what I was looking for, but useful nonetheless.
I was hoping for something that'd combine everything together for me - that command (apparently) just calls the INFO command on each node in the cluster.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what it does. Alternatively, although strictly not build into Redis, you can use the RedisGears module to run a simple script that uses the `ShardIDReader`, `execute()` a call to `INFO`, and aggregate the results.

Comment: I'm a tad late, but I'm going to accept this as the answer. Again, it's not technically what I was trying to do, it's close enough that I can work with it. Thanks!